# Switch external API management instance to internal

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

There is no option in the interface, but I'm still curious whether there might be an API or script somewhere that allows us to change an existing Azure API Management instance from External mode to Internal mode. The only real difference seems to be an internal IP vs public facing IP.

Reason to do so is an architecture change on our side (you learn things...) which now allows us to run it internally with an application gateway in front.

Answer (score 3):

If you're mean internal/external as in VNET then you're free to change VNET mode on Virtual network settings page of APIM service.

Comment: Been looking in the wrong place, sometimes it's simpler then you thought :)